# Application kill of spark on yarn via Zeppelin

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

Is there a recommended way to application kill spark on yarn from inside Zeppelin (using scala)? In the spark shell I use

```
:q
```

and it cleanly exits the shell, kills the application on yarn, and unreserves the cores I was using.

I've found that I can use

```
sys.exit
```

which does kill the application on yarn successfully, but it also throws an error and requires that I restart the interpreter if I want to start a new session. If I'm actively running another notebook with a separate instance of the same interpreter then sys.exit isn't ideal because I can't restart the interpreter until I've finished the work in the second notebook.

Comment: It is looking like there isn't a simple answer to this question. If I could add a follow-up, does anyone understand why :q doesn't work or know a way to make colon commands like :q work in zeppelin? Are they somehow specific to the REPL in a way that zeppelin can't reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to go to the YARN UI and kill the application there.  It should be running on port 8088 of your primary name node.  However, this will require a restart of the service, as well.

Ideally you let YARN deal with this, though.  Just because Zeppelin will start Spark with a specified number of executors and cores doesn't mean these are "reserved" in the way you think.  These cores are still available for other containers.  YARN manages these resources very well.  Unless you have a limited cluster and/or are doing something that requires every last drop of resource management from YARN then you should be fine to leave the Spark application that Zeppelin is using alone.

Comment: Perhaps we have YARN setup differently on our cluster. If I have an application running on YARN with x cores reserved then those cores are not available to other users. If enough users run applications that all the cores on our cluster are reserved, then any additional application will have to wait until cores free up before her application can run. Killing the app through the UI is effectively the same as yarn application -kill, which as you point out will work, but is no better than sys.exit.

Answer (score 0):

You could try restarting the Zeppelin Spark interpreter (which can be done from within the interpreter settings page). This should kill the Zeppelin app, but will only restart the interpreter (and hence the Zeppelin app), when you try executing a paragraph again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The challenge is that I'm looking for something more like sys.exit which will kill the yarn app when a paragraph is executed. This is helpful when I kick off a few long running paragraphs at the end of the day and then want to have my yarn app killed once those paragraphs finish. Also, as I mentioned above, the only downside of sys.exit is that I have to restart the interpreter after using it which I'm trying to avoid for when I'm running multiple notebooks with the same interpreter